# When I place return false inside the nested for loops, why is that automatically returned?

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I'm trying to write a function that returns true if there is a pair in a hand of five cards. It works when I place return false before the last closing curly bracket. When I place the return false inside the nested for loops, it's automatically returned. Why?

```
var cards = [
  {value: 4, suit: 'Clubs'},
  {value: 8, suit: 'Hearts'},
  {value: 7, suit: 'Spades'},
  {value: 5, suit: 'Clubs'},
  {value: 8, suit: 'Diamonds'},
  ]

function pair(handOfCards){
    for (var i=0; i<handOfCards.length; i++){
        for (var j=i+1; j<handOfCards.length; j++){
            if(handOfCards[i].value===handOfCards[j].value){
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it is how javascript works :) Wherever you put a return, function scope ends

Comment: you return too early, because you are still looping.

Comment: Because you return false no matter what. Simple debugging or "playing computer" will tell you why--when you hit the `return` statement outside of a condition you... return. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return "The `return` statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller."

Comment: Just move the `return false` out of the for loops, because it should return false only if true shouldn't be returned. `return`, in javascript, stops any further execution **of its function block**.

Answer (score 1):

To move you a bit further, you could use a single loop approach and use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for visited values.

```js
function pair(handOfCards) {
    var i,
        values = new Set;

    for (i = 0; i < handOfCards.length; i++) {
        if (values.has(handOfCards[i].value)) { // check set
            return true;
        }
        values.add(handOfCards[i].value);       // add value to set
    }
    return false;
}

var cards1 = [{ value: 4, suit: 'Clubs' }, { value: 8, suit: 'Hearts' }, { value: 7, suit: 'Spades' }, { value: 5, suit: 'Clubs' }, { value: 8, suit: 'Diamonds' }],
    cards2 = [{ value: 4, suit: 'Clubs' }, { value: 8, suit: 'Diamonds' }];

console.log(pair(cards1)); //  true
console.log(pair(cards2)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the MDN:

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Hence, the issue is that whenever your criteria is not satisfied, the entire function is stopped, hence the for loop is broken and returns false whenever the if fails.

To solve the issue, just move the return statement **outside** of the for loops, so that if no pair is found, `false` is returned.

```
function pair(handOfCards){
    for (var i=0; i<handOfCards.length; i++){
        for (var j=i+1; j<handOfCards.length; j++){
            if(handOfCards[i].value===handOfCards[j].value){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false; // <-- return false statement moved here.
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j92acpdn/

Answer (score 0):

i=0 the first run through the inner loop meaning you are checking for a match with card.value: 4

With the return false in the current position it will loop once where j=[1,..,4] and if there are no other cards with value: 4 it will return false.

The return false needs to be outside the loops to allow checking of all the values i=[1-4].

Answer (score -1):

**`return` statement stops the further execution of the function**. In your code it will return value no matter that condition is satisfied or not.

Even if you put `else` before `return false` still it will do that same and `return` in the first loop.

Answer (score -1):

If you break down your code to this for loop:

```
for (var j=i+1; j<handOfCards.length; j++){
            if(handOfCards[i].value===handOfCards[j].value){
                return true
            }
            return false
}
```

You can see that return false is called right after the if statement, meaning this will only go through 1 iteration of the for loop, then return false.

One way to fix this would be to add a boolean `found` value that is initialized to false. Instead of returning true when the match is found, change the found boolean to true. At the end of the function, return the `found` value, regardless of true or false.